# Prevent to change URL adress or get custom error for ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a HttpModule for QueryString Encryption in ASP.NET using C#. When I try to change the URL I get an error on the server side. How can I avoid getting this error and instead just show the user a custom 404 page when they change the URL?

For example in YouTube if the link is something like "watch?v=uNhD35RmLb4", and you change it to an invalid (or non-existent) ID, YouTube sends to you the 'VIDEO NOT FOUND' page. How can I do the same, and avoid getting the error server side?

My code where I get the error is:

```
byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
```

> invalid length for a base-64 char array or string

I haven't thrown an error code.

Here's the code for my HttpModule:

```
public class QueryStringModule : IHttpModule
{
    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Nothing to dispose
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    #endregion

    private const string PARAMETER_NAME = "enc=";
    private const string ENCRYPTION_KEY = "key";

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Request.Url.OriginalString.Contains("aspx") && context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("?"))
        {
            string query = ExtractQuery(context.Request.RawUrl);
            string path = GetVirtualPath();

            if (query.StartsWith(PARAMETER_NAME, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Decrypts the query string and rewrites the path.
                string rawQuery = query.Replace(PARAMETER_NAME, string.Empty);
                string decryptedQuery = Decrypt(rawQuery);
                context.RewritePath(path, string.Empty, decryptedQuery);
            }
            else if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
            {
                // Encrypt the query string and redirects to the encrypted URL.
                // Remove if you don't want all query strings to be encrypted automatically.
                string encryptedQuery = Encrypt(query);
                context.Response.Redirect(path + encryptedQuery);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the current URL and extracts the virtual path without query string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The virtual path of the current URL.</returns>
    private static string GetVirtualPath()
    {
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        path = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf("?"));
        path = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        return path;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses a URL and returns the query string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL to parse.</param>
    /// <returns>The query string without the question mark.</returns>
    private static string ExtractQuery(string url)
    {
        int index = url.IndexOf("?") + 1;
        return url.Substring(index);
    }

    #region Encryption/decryption

    /// <summary>
    /// The salt value used to strengthen the encryption.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly static byte[] SALT = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY.Length.ToString());

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts any string using the Rijndael algorithm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputText">The string to encrypt.</param>
    /// <returns>A Base64 encrypted string.</returns>
    public static string Encrypt(string inputText)
    {
        //string result;
        //result = Decrypt(inputText);
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT);

        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16)))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    return "?" + PARAMETER_NAME + Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a previously encrypted string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputText">The encrypted string to decrypt.</param>
    /// <returns>A decrypted string.</returns>
    public static string Decrypt(string inputText)
    {

        RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);

        PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT);

        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    byte[] plainText = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
                    int decryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText, 0, decryptedCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to find the server code  that causes the "i get error on server side" and change it so that instead of throwing an error it sets the response status code to 404. The alternative is to deploy a [custom error page](https://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/) that looks like a 404 page.

Comment: Wrap your decrypt code of the query string in a try catch, on catch return Http code 404

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping `Decrypt()` in a `TryDecrypt()` variant, a bit like `int.TryParse()`:

```
public static bool TryDecrypt(string inputText, out string result)
{
    try
    {
        result = Decrypt(inputText);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
string result;
if (YourClass.TryDecrypt(text, out result))
{
    // use result
}
else
{
    // return appropriate response
}
```

If needed you can improve it by adding logging to the `catch` block, catching specific exceptions, providing status values with more detail than `true/false`, etc, etc.

Comment: i didnt know sorry.i edited the post now. i posted to you my simple code. not edited with TryEncrypt. cause i dont really know where should i paste this codes. i tried but it was error. cause of that i just enter normal code for you to understanding easily